# Rails 3 non-resourceful namespaced route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I noticed that

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :manage do
    get 'list'
  end
end
```

Actually successfully calls following action (for /admin/manage/list):

```
class Admin::ManageController
  def list
    render :text => 'success'
  end
end
```

Which is kind of intuitive (that's why i tried it), but it's not covered anywhere in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Can someone tell for sure that it's standard expected functionality that won't stop working after next version or something?

Answer (score 1):

It is not unexpected and is designed to work like that. However, a more typical way of doing it would be

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :manage do
     collection do
       get 'list'
     end
  end
end
```

The main difference between `namespace` and `resources` is that the latter, by default, provides the standard routes for CRUD actions. Both of them route to `Admin::ManageController`.

They have similar options as well. See the docs for [`namespace`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/namespace) and [`resources`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources/resources)

If `Manage` is a resource that can be created and destroyed in your app, it makes more sense to use `resources`. If it is just an identifier to separate routes for certain actions then use `namespace`.

Comment: Thanks, you probably meant to write "resource :manage" (singular), so that it won't expect id for every method.
Also it's very strange that there's no documentation that says how routes works for 'get/post' directly inside namespace.

Comment: By the way, writing "resources :manage do" like this, won't create default RESTful actions?
So to make it work for me I'd need to write:
resource :manage, :only => [] do
get 'list'
end

Comment: not sure I understand....does the way I have it not work? may be you can update your question with new detail.

Comment: @KaplanIlya added `collection` to route without `id`